# Is there an embeddable FLV player with external audio support?

Tags: flash, flv

I'm looking for an embeddable FLV player that lets me specify a custom audio track that overrides (i.e. mutes and players over) the existing audio (if any) in the FLV file. I don't want to do any re-encoding - I simply want to specify a playlist of videos and an external audio track.

I looked through the JWPlayer and FlowPlayer docs and neither of them support this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using two players, one for audio, one for video, and muting the audio part of the video player?

I have done something similar successfully using [JPlayer](http://jplayer.org). (The video in my case was without sound and I used a second player instance to add the sound. But I don't see why this shouldn't work even when the video has audio of its own.)

Comment: I considered this, but the processing lag will cause the two videos to play out of sync and I can't have that. jPlayer does look interesting, though.